# How to correctly use Bootstrap column for text above div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This code is really confusing me. I have the text "Ways to Win" above multiple div's. The problem is that the text is disrupting the flow of the div's. But if I remove the text from the Bootstrap column, it won't be responsive and flow with the rest of the divs.

How do I make the text flow correctly with the other divs, but also not disrupt the divs below it?

```css
/* Ways to Win */

#win_text {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

.win_box {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  height: 110px;
  width: 196px;
  border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  border-bottom: none !important;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 50px !important;
}

#video {
    font-size: 45px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: 28px;
    left: 80px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #353535;
}

.win_box:hover .description {
  border: 1px solid #2A6496;
}

.win_box:hover  {
  border: 1px solid #2A6496;
}

.description {
  position: relative;
  top: 63px;
  left: -1px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: none !important;
  border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  width: 196px !important;
}

.win_link {
  text-decoration: nonew !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

#win_row {
  max-width: 1550px;
}

/* End of Ways to Win */
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Ways to Win -->

<br>
 
 <div class='row' id='win_row'>
   
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    
    <!-- Title -->
    <span id='win_text'> Ways to Win </span> <br>
          
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  <!-- BREAK -->
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
  
  <!-- Win Boxes -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't use spans for titles, they need to be block elements. I also put your title in its own row so it stays separate from the content below it.

Also, don't use break tags to create layout, they don't clear your rows and they add extra space that's harder to control.

Your layout now works, you just need to sort out spacing between the title and the videos:

```css
/* Ways to Win */

#win_text {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

.win_box {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  height: 110px;
  width: 196px;
  border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  border-bottom: none !important;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 50px !important;
}

#video {
    font-size: 45px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: 28px;
    left: 80px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #353535;
}

.win_box:hover .description {
  border: 1px solid #2A6496;
}

.win_box:hover  {
  border: 1px solid #2A6496;
}

.description {
  position: relative;
  top: 63px;
  left: -1px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: none !important;
  border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  width: 196px !important;
}

.win_link {
  text-decoration: nonew !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

#win_row {
  max-width: 1550px;
}

/* End of Ways to Win */
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Ways to Win -->

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <!-- Title -->
    <div id='win_text'> Ways to Win </div>
</div>
 
 <div class='row' id='win_row'>
   
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>

          
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  <!-- BREAK -->
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id='title'>
    <a href='#' class='win_link'> <div class='win_box' style='background: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8sME-VxUQQA/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=EgyGW3D0KWyu5ei-2aUz8FPI_Jc");'> <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" id='video'></i>
   
   <div class='description'> Earn 5 Points </div>
   
   </div> </a>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
</div>
  
  <!-- Win Boxes -->
```